# Do we need the visitor for annotation processing in java 6?

Tags: java, annotations

I searched for examples which may answer my question, but can't find any useful or complete ones.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: I didn't write any code, just a question in general, are there any nice examples? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want to do. Do you mean build-time annotation processing (APT)? What visitor are you talking about?

Comment: I guess he means `javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationValueVisitor`

Comment: Yes, yes, because in APT, we need to have a visitor to viste a declaration which defined in DeclarationVisitor. But in some sources of java 6, i didn't see this kind of method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't.

The following lines give you all the annotation information for a `Class`. Similarly you can use it for `Method` and `Field` objects

```
Annotation[] annotations = someObject.getClass().getAnnotations();
YourAnnotation annotation = 
     someObject.getClass().getAnnotation(YourAnnotation.class);
boolean annotationPresent = 
     someObject.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(YourAnnotation.class);
```